# Beamer columns environment in article document

Tags: beamer, two-column

I'd like to use something like `beamer`'s `\columns` environment in an article-like document. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

I found this: ([beamer blocks in ordinary article-style document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/beamer-blocks-in-ordinary-article-style-document)) which shows how to use `beamer`'s `block` environments in an article-like document, but it didn't show how to use the columns.

Comment: The `columns` environment internally uses `minipage`. You can use `minipage`s in any document class.

Comment: Thanks. If you make your comment an answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46115/15925  If you agree, let us know and we will close this question as such.

Comment: I guess the question is the same, but the answer given doesn't give the answer I was looking for. The answer in the proposed duplicate is for columns that flow from one to the next. That's not what I'm looking for and that isn't what the beamer columns environment does.

Comment: @Jeremy I added an answer with a simple example.

Comment: The `multicol` package might be the way to go.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `columns` environment internally uses `minipage`, so you can simply use `minipage`s in your document; a simple example (I added some frames just as visual guidelines). The `\Colsep` length can be used to control the separation between the `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\Colsep
\setlength\Colsep{10pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][6cm][c]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\Colsep\relax}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c][6cm][c]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\Colsep\relax}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a fixed height (`6cm`) for the inner `minipage`s and center alignment but this, of course, is optional.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina It worked great for me with code listings too