# Beamer multicolumn vertical alignment problem

Tags: beamer, multicolumn, alignment

I have the following slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Why does this happen?}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{center}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text
  \item More text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{center}
\columnbreak

\begin{center}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text
  \item More text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the second column, the vertical spacing between the two \items is all wrong.  What may be causing this problem?

[image: Beamer vertical alignment problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Because you were not using the built--in \texttt{columns}}

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text
  \item More text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Text
  \item More text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then I won't get the columns if I use \documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle} (that is, if I also want to generate notes from the slide).  I thought using multicol would let me have columns in both.

Comment: @GrB That's probably true, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113123/121799) is a workaround. Whether or not someone has successfully redefined the columns environment for the presentation mode I do not know. That is, my answer may not be the best way for having something that also works in article mode in the sense that the columns will be next to each other. (Whether there is a way to make sure that things that look good on a slide look always good in article mode, I don't know.)